# Call to undefined function Zend_Json_Expr()?

Tags: json, zend-framework

I need to JSONize some data without quotes around the values for Javascript purposes.

I am following examples like

```
$data = array(
    'onClick' => new Zend_Json_Expr('function() {'
              . 'alert("I am a valid javascript callback '
              . 'created by Zend_Json"); }'),
    'other' => 'no expression',
);
$jsonObjectWithExpression = Zend_Json::encode(
    $data,
    false,
    array('enableJsonExprFinder' => true)
);
```

and then returning the $jsonObjectWithExpression, but I get an exception

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Zend_Json_Expr() in ...

I'm pretty sure my version 1.10.8 supports this feature, since I can see the class in json/Expr.php

Do I need to import/include this class somehow?  I haven't had to import any other Zend classes..

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Zend_Autoloader` or `Zend_Application`
or just `require_once('/path/to/Zend/Json/Expr.php')`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you're using the **new** keyword?

The error message seems to state you're attempting to call a function named `Zend_Json_Expr`

Comment: ...and that would be it.  I feel stupid, since I lost a couple hours on that one.  In my defense, the docs exclude 'new'.

Comment: It would have been slightly more obvious if you'd actually pasted in your code as your question does not contain any errors. The API (http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Json/Expr/Zend_Json_Expr.html) is incorrect however the manual (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.advanced.html#zend.json.advanced.expr) is not